# Set date as three days before

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if this looks like the right way to do things:

```
UPDATE table SET `date2` = date_sub(`date1`,interval -2 day);
```

I would like to set the date on the `date2` column to two days before the date on the `date1` column.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: A date subtract of -2 = Adding 2 days... The date_sub knows to subtract...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seldom use the DATE_SUB() or DATE_ADD() functions, because it's more clear to just use date arithmetic.

```
UPDATE table SET `date2` = `date1` - interval 2 day;
```